# Designing UI for schedule app (ios Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app for iPhone and it should display time tables for various weekly programs (this is an app for a community center). Here is an example of the data:

Mon: 3pm - 4pm: Jogging, 4pm - 5pm: Group Prayers, 6pm - 7pm: Dinner
Wed: 5pm - 6pm: Speech by Dr. X, 6pm - 7pm: Questions and answers, 7pm - 8pm: Discussoin
Fri: ....

The data is fetched from the web and it's read-only.

I want to display the data similar to the image below. So here are two questions I have:

1. How did this person accomplish this? I'm assuming he put tableview within scrollview (you can swipe left and Sunday tab appears). How??

[image]

2. Is there a better way to dislpay the data? If so, please give suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [pagemenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) to integrate this UI

Comment: Thanks!! Do you have any other idea for designing the UI?

Comment: What do you mean by better way to display the data? are you asking for a better design?

Comment: yeah a better design

Comment: `pagemenu` looks fine to go with.

Comment: Now how do i create multiple tableviews based on the #ofdays? (eg. if i get 4 days worth of schedule fetched from the web api, i need to create 4 view controllers to add in pagemenu)...

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the better solution for this is to use a pan gesture recognizer to move the table view and the other table view for sunday.
2. I don't know if there is better way. But the standard iOS calendar uses a different interface and navigation to show the same info.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scrollView and top of it add button as an array. Then make the content size of scrollView as nos of button * width. It might help you.

I think this is the best way to fulfill your criteria.

Let me know if you want any details of above solution.